# data not refatching after invalidate query in react0query

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query, next.js13

i using react-query for fetching some data in my admin panel website. after mutation i am in onSuccess function invalidate query. this invalidate working currect bot cuery does not clear in ReactQueryDevtools and not refatching updated data.
this is my code

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB9K2.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5hED.png)
```

i using refresh token in interceptor axios, firstly i thinking this is a problm but my new request for reftching does not send

Comment: Please, put your code here as code, not links to images on external sites.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.